# How to require input to a column in Excel when another cell has a specific value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with Student Name, Race/Ethnicity, Gender, Degree, Major, Status, Year Started, and Career After Graduation as columns. Thank you for those who helped me with my codes for requiring input in columns Race/Ethnicity, Gender, and Degree if Student Name is provided in column A. Now I need to do something additional. If the value of Status in column F is "Graduated", I want Career After Graduation column (column H) to be filled out too. The closest codes I could come up with are listed below, and I now have a problem.

When Status in column F has a value of "Graduated", Excel not only requires a user to fill out Career After Graduation in column H, but also other columns. How should I modify the codes, so only column H will be required?

Thank you!

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rngCell As Range, strBlanks As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strBlanks = vbNullString
For Each rngCell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F20").Cells
If rngCell.Value = "Graduated" Then
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 1)) < 1 Then
strBlanks = strBlanks & IIf(Len(strBlanks) > 0, ",", "") & _
Replace(rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1,1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address, "$", "")
End If
End If
Next

If Not strBlanks = vbNullString Then
MsgBox "Entries required in cells " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strBlanks
Cancel = True
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [Autofilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) to avoid looping through cells and have a one-shot operation

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim toBeFilledAddress  As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--| '<-- change "Sheet1" with your actual sheet name
        With .Range("A1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| reference its range in columns A:B from row 1 to column "A" last non empty cell row
            .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="Graduated" '<--| filter referenced range on its 6th column with "Graduated"
            .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="" '<--|filter referenced range again on its 8th column with blanks
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then toBeFilledAddress = .Offset(1, 7).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address(False, False)  '<--| store all matching cells address
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back
    End With

    If toBeFilledAddress <> "" Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
        MsgBox "Entries required in cells " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & toBeFilledAddress
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub '<--| this line could be avoided unless you're planning to add more lines after "End If"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer as solution. Thank you

Comment: This is a dumb question, but how do I accept your answer as solution? I am very new to stackoverflow. :p

Comment: You must click on a green tick next to the top-left of my answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

why do you use the following?

& vbCrLf & vbCrLf

it seems that your code works fine but some how those two variables are getting filled with other columns.

Also, which of the columns does it return besides H? And when is the user supposed to be prompted to enter in the values?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just found some codes online and modified them. I am very new to VBA and have no idea what "& vbCrLf & vbCrLf " is. @bdpolinsky